# How to trigger click event for a mock method vue test utils

Tags: javascript, vue.js, jestjs, vue-test-utils

I'm trying to use vue-test-utils and I'm at a moment where I should check if the click of the button calls a method I created

My button and method in vue file:

```
<template>
<section>
    <button
        id="buttonInstagram"
        @click="redirectInstagramApi()"
        class="btn btn--primary btn--lg mb-2"
        type="button"
    >
        Login
    </button>
</section>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    methods: {
        redirectInstagramApi () {
            this.loadingInstagram = true
            authInfluencer.getInstagramData()
                .then(redirectUrl => { window.open(redirectUrl) })
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

My spec file:

```
describe('Influencer.vue', () => {
      beforeEach(() => {
        wrapper = shallowMount(Influencer)
      })
    
      it('calls redirect to Instagram API when button is clicked', async () => {
        const redirectInstagram = jest
            .spyOn(Influencer.methods, 'redirectInstagramApi')
    
        wrapper.find('#buttonInstagram').trigger('click')
    
        (redirectInstagram).toHaveBeenCalled()
      })
})
```

When i run Jest i receive this error:

```
[vue-test-utils]: find did not return #buttonInstagram, cannot call trigger() on empty Wrapper
```

Comment: And what's the problem, exactly? Give a [mre]. Your indentation is all over the place, but it looks like you forgot to actually type `expect`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I edited the post please check if it's clearer

Comment: Is `<section>` the HTML tag or a vue component? Also, can you double check you're importing the correct `.vue` file?

Comment: I still doubt this is representative because `methods: ` outside an object is a [*label*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label). Why shallow mount something that has no child components anyway? And don't spy on parts of the thing you're supposed to be testing - test the *behaviour*, not the *implementation*, in this case test what the method *does*.

Comment: @tao yes is a vue component.Sorry, i forgot the 'export default', im beginner using stack overflow

Comment: @jonrsharpe but if I test if a method is being called correctly when clicking a button it would be a way to test what the method does, am I wrong?

Comment: If `<section>` is a vue component, `.shallowMount()` will replace it with `<section-stub>` and none of its contents will be rendered. Therefore you won't find your button. That's what `shallowMount` does. It replaces all children components with stubs because you declare: I don't care about children here. It's only this component I'm testing.  Use `.mount()` instead. Or move this test inside `<section>`'s unit testing.

Comment: But why are you overriding default HTML elements? I bet developing a [`<div>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/div) vue component doesn't seem right to you. Which begs the question: what's different for [`<section>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/section)? ***Important note:*** all components not containing a dash in their name are actually invalid HTML. The reason is for specifically ruling out any possible conflicts with existing or *not-yet-existing* html native elements, as those will ***never*** contain dashes. That's the convention.